# How to add existing User Assigned Managed Identity to new Resource Group in Azure using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

Below is the scenario:
We have a User Assigned Managed Identity in Resource Group 'A' and we are creating a new Resource Group 'B' and want to add MSI from Resource Group A to be B.

How can we achieve this via Azure CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `az identity list -g '<resource group name>'` to get the `id`, then use the command below, the `id` means the User Assigned Managed Identity resource id,  it works fine on my side.

```
az resource move --destination-group '<destination resource group>' --ids '<User Assigned Managed Identity resource id >'
```

[image]
[image]

**Update**:

```
az role assignment create --resource-group '<resourcegroupname>' --role 'Contributor' --assignee '<service principal objectId>'
```

Check in the portal:

[image]
**Besides**, you could find the ObjectId in Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications(All applications), just search for your User Assigned Managed Identity name.

Comment: This will move out this resource from my Resource Group 'A'. We need to add/assign Contributor role to an MSI in IAM Section to Resource Group 'B'

Comment: @AakashMohan If you create `User Assigned Managed Identity`, there will be a service principal automatically. When you add it to IAM in a resource group, it essentially add the service principal to it, you could refer to my update.

Comment: I will test this and get back to you.

Comment: It worked just fine. thanks for your help. I had to use objectid to make it run

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial step shows how to grant permissions to a user assigned managed identity, via CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/msi-tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm#grant-your-user-assigned-identity-access-to-a-resource-group-in-azure-resource-manager